# Django prevent image upload containing possible XSS code

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I am creating a site that users can upload images. I am using `django-storages` to forward these images to S3 bucket, but I recently read the security docs on Django's site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/security/#user-uploaded-content

> Django’s media upload handling poses some vulnerabilities when that media is served in ways that do not follow security best practices. Specifically, an HTML file can be uploaded as an image if that file contains a valid PNG header followed by malicious HTML. This file will pass verification of the library that Django uses for ImageField image processing (Pillow). When this file is subsequently displayed to a user, it may be displayed as HTML depending on the type and configuration of your web server.

It tells me about this vulnerability but it does not provide me an efective way of protecting against these vulnerabilities. Which is the top 3rd most vulnerable attack in websites.

> Consider serving static files from a cloud service or CDN to avoid some of these issues.

I am using S3 to serve my media files, it does say to avoid some of the vulnarabilities described in the section, but is does not say *which*.

**My question:** Is uploading and serving images to and from AWS S3 vulnerable to these attacks, and if *it does not*, what is an effective way of *sanitizing* the content of the image ?

**Edit for bounty:** I host the images on S3, what are type of attack or vulnerabilities can happen ? And how to prevent such attacks ?

Comment: Having a separate domain name (even if they are hosted on the same server) and a CORS policy for the main domain should prevent most attacks. You may also consider re-encoding the uploaded PNG (and other image) files using  PIL/Pillow before storing them to make sure that they are legitimate image files.

Comment: @Selcuk Does images served from S3 are walled by CORS policy ? it itself is served from `s3.amazon.x` which is different from my domain.

Comment: The same-origin policy should be enforced by your main domain name, not s3. Using s3 (or any other domain name) simply lets your web server differentiate requests originated from the main domain name and from the media files. See [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) for a Django specific implementation.

Comment: @Selcuk I do have cors settings set up, because I am using Django REST, is the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` in which I need to take care of? or do I need to do something else to prevent such attack ?

Comment: It is hard to guarantee that something will protect against all kinds of attacks but it's a good start. Welcome to information security.

Comment: @Selcuk Is this question a question that the industry wants to answer too ? I can be worrying too much then. But will really want to push all the safety practices as far as possible.

Comment: There is no such thing as too much worrying. It's a compromise between security and convenience. Even the simplest web application is a very sophisticated piece of machinery with many moving parts. It is almost impossible to make sure that each part is secure. The best you can do is to try and plug the ones you know about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just verify that the file is a valid image?:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(file)
image.verify()
```

As another poster has suggested, you can indeed attempt a transformation and check if an exception is thrown, but verify() will probably be quicker.

Or maybe you can try detecting the type?:

```
import imghdr
path = 'Image.jpg'
imghdr.what(path)
```

Or

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('myimage.png')
image.format
```

Using any of the above methods, you can determine if the file is actually an image or not. If it is not an image, then consider the file as spurious, and do not output it on any of your web pages. By not outputting the file, there is no risk of XSS from this vector, because even if the file is HTML, by not outputting it on your page, it cannot compromise your page.

Comment: Afaik, they can bypass the detection by faking the headers, or that doesn't work like that ?

Comment: Then what does Django docs means exactly by "Specifically, an HTML file can be uploaded as an image if that file contains a valid PNG header followed by malicious HTML. This file will pass verification of the library that Django uses for ImageField image processing (Pillow)."

Comment: @Paaksing that refers only to uploading a file. Just because a file has a png header or extension doesn’t mean it is actually a png file. The code in my answer does not use headers - it looks at the actual file, so the header should be irrelevant. Try it.

Comment: Using the above code you can verify if the file is an image file or not. If it isn’t, then do not output it on your page - if you do not output it, then you do not risk xss.

Comment: Or to be precise, you do not risk XSS from this vector.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible solution comes from the [Pillow library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) itself.

Even if someone can Manipulate the headers of an HTML File to make them look as PNG files, when you try doing some operation on them (say [resizing](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=thumbnail#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail)), it will simply not work and throw an error, so you can capture it inside a try except block and warn/flag the user for malicious intent.

If you don't want to reduce the quality of any image given to you, then you can resize to the original image size, it will work without compromising the quality of image.

Comment: Currently I am using `easy_thumbnails` for the images to do the autocrop, after looking at its dependency, it uses Pillow, do you think it is ok to trust it from there ?

Comment: @Paaksing Yes, I think it should be secured, but just for safety, why dont you try it out and see it for yourself. But i am almost 100% sure it is secure. Hope the answer helps, kindly upvote if it does. It feels good :)